# How to Offset Pandas Pearson Correlation with Datetime Index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pearson-correlation

I'm trying to get a correlation value for a previous week's inputs to the following week's output.

For the sake of this example I've set it up where each week's input will be the following week's Output, and the `df.corr()` should give a `1.000000` result.

My original data looks like this:

```
Date      Input     Output
1/1/2010    73         73
1/7/2010     2         73
1/13/2010    3          2
1/19/2010    4          3
```

Full sample data uploaded here:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4xdnV0LFZI1MzRUOUJkcUY4ajQ

Here's my code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('pearson.csv')
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], errors = 'coerce')
df = df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date']))
df = df[['Input', 'Output']]
x = df.corr(method = 'pearson', min_periods=1)
print(x)
```

And as a newbie here's where I'm stuck.  I don't see a `shift` option built in the function and not sure how to do this.

Any and all help is appreciated.

Thank you,
Me

Comment: BTW that's every 6 days.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you do `.corr`on a dataframe, it will produce a correlation matrix.

In your case, you just want the correlation between two time series and you can achieve this with the code below. Note that the `.corr` method for a time series requires the parameter `other`, which is the series to compute the correlation with.

```
df["Input"].corr(df["Output"].shift(-1), method = 'pearson', min_periods = 1) #1
```

If instead you want the correlation matrix, you should first create a dataframe with shifted Output and then compute the correlation:

```
temp_df = pd.concat([df['Input'], df['Output'].shift(-1)], axis = 1).dropna()
temp_df.corr(method = 'pearson', min_periods = 1)   

#        Input  Output
#Input     1.0     1.0
#Output    1.0     1.0
```

Comment: Congrat to 1k ;)